# Select disk destination on app installation with keyboard

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, install, shortcut

On most app installers you have to select a disk where you want the installation. Is there any possible way to select it without the use of the trackpad or the mouse?

Answer (score 6):

Once you have reached the screen that requests you to "select the disk where you want to install macOS using keyboard", to select the disk destination:

1. Turn "VoiceOver" on by pressing:  cmd + F5  (laptops might need to
   use "cmd + fn + F5"

   2. Move around on a pane you are interacting with
      by using the following:  Control-Option-Arrows (up/down/left/right) Example:  control + option + "up arrow"  --  You will move your selection to the next selection above...
   3. To select a sub-category (e.g. in a grid or table) use: 
      Control-Option-Shift-Down Arrow
   4. To exit a sub-category use: Control-Option-Shift-Up Arrow

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/message/31115644#31115644

Answer (score 0):

Press 'Tab' button on keyboard and/or arrow keys. After you get to the required disk, press 'Enter'.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work on the mac os Sierra installer.

Comment: Might depend on having System prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Full Keyboard Access set to 'All controls'

Comment: @Tetsujin There are no system prefs available in the installer. The VoiceOver trick below works though. :)

Comment: @JeremyWiebe - the system prefs are in the same place they always are...  Menu > System Preferences...